# Trying to delete the parent of a HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to delete the parent of a HTML element with the use of JQuery. The click event concern the span element, i'm trying by then to delete the whole `<tr>` elements.

Here's the DOM tree :

```
{% for element in elements %}
 <tr>
  <th scope=row>Kate</th>
    <td><span id="update">Update</span></td>
    <td id="delete">Delete</td>              
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And here's the JQuery code trying to delete the parent element of td > span.

```
$('body').on('click','#delete',function(){
   var td = $(this).parent();
   $(td).parent().fadeOut('slow');
});
```

This code never work for me, so any one to help please.

Comment: if this delete button is there for every td then give it a class since id must be unique

Answer (score 0):

first of all don't assign `id` to the `delete` button

```
{% for element in elements %}
 <tr>
  <th scope=row>Kate</th>
    <td><span id="update">Update</span></td>
    <td class="delete">Delete</td>              
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Now assign the click event handler to the `delete` class

```
$('body').on('click','.delete',function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('slow', function(){
     $( this ).remove();
   });
});
```

Comment: @KubiRoazhon can you try again? Also expand on `it dosen't work`.

Comment: @KubiRoazhon which two examples. I meant - can you expand on what happens when this code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(".your_child_element").unwrap()
```